# Rust multiline raw string literal without new line characters

Tags: rust

I want to write a multiline string in Rust which I can pass to the format macro (`format!`) to produce a formatted string using two variable strings.

Here is an example test code.

```
fn main() {
    let string1 = "username";
    let string2 = "password";
    
    let sasl_jaas_config = format!(
            r#"
            org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule 
            required username="{}" 
            password="{}";
            "#,
            string1,
            string2);

    println!("{}", sasl_jaas_config);
    println!("done");
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
            org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule 
            required username="username" 
            password="password";
            #note new line is here with leading spaces !!!
done
```

There are several issues with this

- The string contains newlines
- The string contains leading whitespace on every line

What I actually want is this output

```
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="username" password="password";
```

Which I have been able to produce using this modified code

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello world!");
    
    let string1 = "username";
    let string2 = "password";
    
    let sasl_jaas_config = format!(
            "\
            org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule \
            required username=\"{}\" \
            password=\"{}\";\
            ",
            string1,
            string2);

    println!("{}", sasl_jaas_config);
    println!("done");
}
```

However, using this modified code I have lost many of the advantages of raw strings:

- I had to escape my `"` characters
- Backslash characters are required at the end of each line

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `concat!` to concatenate multiple string literals like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let string1 = "username";
    let string2 = "password";

    let sasl_jaas_config = format!(
        concat!(
            "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule ",
            r#"required username="{}" "#,
            r#"password="{}";"#,
        ),
        string1, string2
    );

    println!("{}", sasl_jaas_config);
    println!("done");
}
```

Output:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="username" password="password";
done
```

or just not include the newlines and whitespace:

```rust
r#"org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="{}" password="{}";"#,
```

Another possibility would be to put the string in question in a different file:
`format_string.txt`

```
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="{}" password="{}";
```

and `include_str!("format_string.txt")` it.

Obviously all have different advantages and issues.

A raw string is exactly that, raw, so any whitespace, newlines, what would be escape characters in a regular string, etc are just verbatimely put into the string.

Answer (score 0):

A rework of the variable `sasl_jaas_config` is terribly inefficient, but You can keep the structure of the raw string as it is.

```
fn main() {
    let string1 = "username";
    let string2 = "password";

    let sasl_jaas_config = format!(
        r#"
            org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule 
            required username="{string1}" 
            password="{string2}";
            "#
    );

    println!(
        "{}",
        sasl_jaas_config
            .split_ascii_whitespace()
            .map(|e| e.to_string())
            .reduce(|acc, s| format!("{acc} {s}"))
            .unwrap()
    );
    println!("done");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=fab7d79deba6e602872572103b455435)